# Multiple Error in view,edit a list of a model

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, instance

i am trying to view and edit the  my customer model-

i am doing is when you open the server for first time the list of customer opens as a link .
as sson as i press suppose customer 1 .

the form appears well pre filled as soon as i make changes  and press save button it gives me error-

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/marketing/editcustomer/2250a9b1-5d25-4bce-b426-e3a4abb45abb/POST
```

I also have back button - I get the same error after pressing back button too!

Then if I go back to the `customerlist(seecustomer)` and I again click on the same or any other customer it gives me the following error-

```
Manager isn't accessible via customer instances
```

sometimes it also gives -

```
First argument to get_object_or_404() must be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet, not 'customer'.
```

my **models.py**

```
class customer(models.Model):
    customerid=models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    customername=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

my views.py

```
def editcustomer(request,customer_pk):
    global customer
    customer=get_object_or_404(customer,pk=customer_pk,user=request.user)
    if request.method=='GET':
        form=createcustomerform(instance=customer)
        return render(request,'marketing/editcustomer.html',{'customer':customer,'form':form})
    else:
        try:
            form=createcustomerform(request.POST,instance=customer)
            form.save()
            return redirect('seecustomer')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request,'marketing/editcustomer.html',{'customer':customer,'form':form,'error':'Incorrect entry'})
```

my html form code-

```
<form action="POST" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<div id="customername"> <span><label for="customername">Company Name</label></span>
  <input type="text" id="customername" name="customername" placeholder="Enter Company's Full name" value="{{ customer.customername}}"> </div>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" type="submit">Save</button>
<br>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" value="Go Back" onclick="history.back(-1)" />
</form>
```

Comment: Use an uppercase for the class, so `Customer`, that way it will *not* clash with the local variable.

Comment: i tried but i  am unable to change change /Rename now

Comment: Well the problem is that your `customer = get_object_or_404(customer, pk=...)`, etc will take the value of customer. This is initially the `customer` class, since you imported that, but in the second run, it is now the `customer` *object*...

Comment: how to rename model name customer to Customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is due to the fact that after the first time `get_object_or_404` is called, `customer` is a `customer` *object*, and no longer the class.

You can import the model for example with an uppercase:

```
from app.models import customer as Customer

def editcustomer(request,customer_pk):
    customer=get_object_or_404(Customer,pk=customer_pk,user=request.user)
    if request.method=='GET':
        form=createcustomerform(instance=customer)
        return render(request,'marketing/editcustomer.html',{'customer':customer,'form':form})
    else:
        try:
            form=createcustomerform(request.POST,instance=customer)
            form.save()
            return redirect('seecustomer')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request,'marketing/editcustomer.html',{'customer':customer,'form':form,'error':'Incorrect entry'})
```

So here we remove the `global` part, and use the alias `Customer`. That being said, I *strongly* advise to use the [PEP-8 style guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and thus write the names of classes in `PerlCase`, not <s>`snake_case`</s>. In that case you can simply import it with:

```
from app.models import Customer

def editcustomer(request,customer_pk):
    customer=get_object_or_404(Customer,pk=customer_pk,user=request.user)
    if request.method=='GET':
        form=createcustomerform(instance=customer)
        return render(request,'marketing/editcustomer.html',{'customer':customer,'form':form})
    else:
        try:
            form=createcustomerform(request.POST,instance=customer)
            form.save()
            return redirect('seecustomer')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request,'marketing/editcustomer.html',{'customer':customer,'form':form,'error':'Incorrect entry'})
```

Comment: i tried changing name and run makemigrations again its giving the following error-ImportError: cannot import name 'customer' from 'marketing.models'

Comment: @ritu: no then you need to use `from app.models import Customer`, so remove the `customer as` part.

Comment: @ritu: the action should be empty, so `<form action="" method="POST">`.